# Manipulate Assembly Instructions

Tags: c++, assembly

I would like to "test" a function in C++ by manipulating its assembly instructions. 
What's the best way to do something like this?

I guess one way is to have it compiled or an executable and then to start that .exe by another program which then tries to manipulate it.
If that function-under-test has a point where its still running but waits for something (i.e. user input) then the simulator (program that starts the function-under-test) does not even need to put some kind of break-point into it.

How can I start a program and manipulate its assembly instructions?

**More clearly:**
Is it actually possible to write a simple simulator that (sets a break-point or for the first step without a break-point) and then access the memory of the running function-under-test to manipulate its assembly instructions?
It would be a very small and simple version of the big gdb.

Comment: Are we talking about offline manipulation (as Paul suggests below) or runtime (JIT-like), which is sometimes refereed to as dynamic binary optimization/translation?

Comment: @Leeor I want to change the program while it is running. Thats why I wrote about a break-point. The perfect solution for my problem would be the option to set the time and location of where to change one/several bits to see then how the function-under-test behaves.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, you can use gdb. If you need to automate it, you can run it under an emulator or a simulator and trigger on that breakpoint (or any other event).

Comment: @Leeor Yes, that's what I try to do: Writing a simple simulator which does exactly what want to (set a break-point or for the first step without a break-point) and then access the memory of the running function-under-test to manipulate its assembly instructions. But what should I start with? How can I start a function-to-test by my selfmade simulator and then manipulate something in that function?

Comment: You *could* do this, but the effort it would take for your "code modifier" to know what it was modifying would be pretty big.  Surely you don't want to modify code which is not in the function of interest? ... to execute directly an illegal instruction? So you code modifier needs an accurate model of how the object code for your function is compiled, complicated by all the stuff the C++ compiler does.  If what you want to do is modify the function itself, you'd be better off modifying the function source code with a program transformation system.  Why do you insist on hacking on the bits?

Comment: @IraBaxter It's about injecting a fault into a function that en/de-codes something by using rsa. For this reason, it's not important for the code-modifier to know what instruction it manipulates. It only needs the option to change every bit it wants and to do this whenever it wants. Then it looks at the result produced by the function-under-test. That's what I mean by a simple-version-of-gnudb.

Comment: If you inject random bytes, mostly what you will get is machine traps.  How does that test anything useful?  What you are trying to do is called "mutation testing", and unless you believe your OS won't trap on illegal instructions/bad memory references, what you probably want to test is that broken implementations (e.g., those that return a value when called) are detectably wrong.  And you didn't address my remark that you random byte injector needs to understand the binary structure of the compiled code in order to hit any location that is actually part of the function.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes that's absolutely right. I want to inject random bytes into that function and I want it to produce wrong output (or I hope that I won't get any wrong output). One big difference (I've not talked about it yet) is that I don't have any operating system. The function to test will run on a microcontroller and whatever I get by these manipulated bits (i.e. page faults or whatever) I want to let it simply happen and see what the calculation returns. I thought each program has its own virtual memory given my the operating system.

Comment: @IraBaxter So why does it cause problems when the function-under-test tries to access the memory at a adress i.e. by a pointer which has been changed and is invalid now? What happens on a microcontroller should be: the function reads some  undefined memory space and takes what it found there to go on with its calculation. And the it produces some strange output.

Comment: I'm astonished that you can say "no operating system", "given my the xxx operating system" and "virtual space".  *If* you build an OS with processes that have virtual space, it is pretty hard to find hardware that will undefined memory space accesses complete without issuing a trap. The fact that you don't seem know this suggests you are not ready to implement such an OS.  That makes answering this question seem a bit pointless. (Building such an OS just to allow mutation testing seems like overkill)

Comment: If you accept that illegal references will cause a trap, ok, then you can implement you random byte storing scheme, and just take illegal instruction/access traps as "returned not value" but this is likely to make your testing incredibly inefficent; most of your store-random attempts will produce these traps, but these traps don not producing any real information about the functional correctness of your module.  So I just don't understand the point.

Comment: Finally, if you are willing to write you own OS, you'll have to define object file format (or you can't load the program into the VM).  At that point, you'll probably have enough background to decide which code regions to hit.   Given that all of this seems predicated on your first implementing an OS with virtual processes, this whole thing appears to be an exercise in fantasy.

Comment: @IraBaxter First, thank you for your quick answer. What I want is far away from implementing a own OS. My considerations are much more simple: Let's say I've got an ATmega and I want to run my function on it. So what this ATmega does is to take what it gets over a i.e. I2C connection then it calculates something and sends the result back (over I2C or similar). So when I open up that ATmega and shoot with a laser on a bit (at a random location) then, what will happen? The ATmega produces errors and does not send anything as result.

Comment: @IraBaxter Or it sends "I've got an error". Or maybe it sends a result that is not the expected one. On this ATmega normally does not run anything like an operating system or am I wrong with that? What could be a problem with simulating such a manipulation on a computer is that a computer indeed has a OS and when the manipulated function produced system-exceptions/traps then what comes out of the function may be something totally different than what would come out on the ATmega. What kind of problems I will get is an other question. My problem is that I don't know how to do the manipulation;)

Comment: You might want to read the tech paper for this: Marcel Heing-Becker, Timo Kamph and Sibylle Schupp. 
Bit-Error Injection for Software Developers, CSMR 2014, Antwerp, Belguim (just heard it presented 5 hours ago).  This is a virtual machine that can set arbitrary bits in the data of your C code.

Answer (score 2):

- write (and test) C++ program foo.cpp
- compile to asembly source (`g++ -Wall -S foo.cpp` - output will be foo.s)
- REPEAT

  - modify foo.s
  - assemble foo.s (`gcc foo.s`)
  - test resulting executable (`./a.out` or `gdb ./a.out`)
- UNTIL done

Comment: Thx for that idea, but I would rather like to manipulate a program while it's running (see my comment)